# Group data having unique keys and values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have a following set of numbers:

```
1  137
1  143
11 37
11 46
11 132
46 65
46 139
69 90
```

Now, I need to group the data by the first value in a way that no group key is present in the group values. So, for instance, if I were to simply group data, I'd get this result:

```
1  137
   143
11 37
   46
   132
46 65
   139
69 90
```

46 here is a group key in the third group and a group value in the second group. In this case I need to merge the group values of the third group into a second group and remove the third group.
The end result of the grouping should look like this:

```
1  137
   143
11 37
   46
   132
   65
   139
69 90
```

I'm relatively new to C#, so I was wondering if there's a fancy way to do it using LINQ.

Comment: There's a `ToLookup` extension method you can call on the which will achieve your first requirement, to create groups including group 46. I'm not sure if it can collapse one group into another as you have asked for but I'll look into it and see.

Comment: I doubt there is a LINQ solution, and even if, it is probably much more efficient and readable to use another approach(like filling dictionary(s) in a loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this LINQ solution:

```
var numbers = new List<Number>
{
    new Number {X = 1, Y = 137},
    new Number {X = 1, Y = 143},
    new Number {X = 11, Y = 37},
    new Number {X = 11, Y = 46},
    new Number {X = 11, Y = 132},
    new Number {X = 46, Y = 65},
    new Number {X = 46, Y = 139},
    new Number {X = 69, Y = 90}
};
var result = numbers.GroupBy(c => c.X);
var result2 = numbers.FirstOrDefault(c => result.Select(d => d.Key).Contains(c.Y));

var finalResult = numbers.Where(x => x.X == result2?.Y)
                         .Select(x =>  { x.X = result2.X;x.Y = x.Y; return x; } )
                         .Union(numbers.Where(c => c.X != result2?.Y)).GroupBy(c => c.X ,
                         (key, element) => new
                         {
                             Key = key,
                            Element = element.Select(c => c.Y).ToList()
                         });
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you

```
public static List<Numbers> setNumbers()
{
    List<Numbers> num = new List<Numbers>();

    num.Add(new Numbers() { Column1 = 1, Column2 = 137 });
    num.Add(new Numbers() { Column1 = 1, Column2 = 143 });
    num.Add(new Numbers() { Column1 = 11, Column2 = 37 });
    num.Add(new Numbers() { Column1 = 11, Column2 = 46 });
    num.Add(new Numbers() { Column1 = 11, Column2 = 132 });
    num.Add(new Numbers() { Column1 = 46, Column2 = 65 });
    num.Add(new Numbers() { Column1 = 46, Column2 = 139 });
    num.Add(new Numbers() { Column1 = 69, Column2 = 90 });


    return num;
}


public static void group()
{
    List<Numbers> numbers = setNumbers();

    var grouppedNumbers = numbers
        .GroupBy(x => x.Column1).ToList();

    grouppedNumbers.AddRange(grouppedNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.First().Column1.Equals(46)).Select(s => new Numbers() { Column1 = 11, Column2 = s.Column2 }).GroupBy(g => g.Column1).ToList());
    grouppedNumbers.Remove(grouppedNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.First().Column1.Equals(46)));



    foreach (var groups in grouppedNumbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(groups.First().Column1);
       foreach(var i in groups)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(i.Column1+" "+ i.Column2);
       }
    }




}
```

Comment: It does seem that way!